# How to check woocommerce rest-API coupon code valid or not?

Tags: android, ios, woocommerce

I developed one e-commerce app using woocommerce rest-API. now I need to add coupons codes feature in-app. I know how to pass coupon code in creating order, but how to check this code is valid or not before creating an order?

Answer (score -1):

For get any coupon code details you need to used below URL, Its return coupon full details.
http://www.domainname.com/wp-json/wc/v3/coupons/?code=your_coupon_code

If coupon code not valid then return blank json data.